# Add result to a dataset without deleting the previous rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Panel` with this structure

```
<asp:Panel ID="Custom" Visible="false" runat="server">
    Search: 
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1"  Visible="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="UserSearchSource" SelectionMode="Multiple" DataTextField="username" DataValueField="username"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserSearchSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:fscauth %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [user] FROM [table] WHERE ([user] LIKE '%' + @username + '%') ORDER BY [username]">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="user" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<br /> <br /> <asp:Button ID="Button2" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

So, I have a `TextBox` which plays the role of a user searcher on the Database, with the result displayed on the  `ListBox`. on Add `Button_Click`, it populates the result in a `DataTable` ,which is after used as a `Gridview` Datasource. What I would like to achieve, is that every time the Add button is clicked, not only adds the result to the `DataTable`, but without deleting the previous list of result. For now what I have been using is:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      List<string> lista = getUserList(ListBox1);

      DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
      DataRow dr = null;
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("user", typeof(string)));
      for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count;i++ )
      {
          dr = dt.NewRow();
          dr["user"] = lista[i].ToString();
          dt.Rows.Add(dr);
      }
      ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;    
      GridView1.Visible = true; 
      GridView1.DataSource = dt;
      GridView1.DataBind();
      Button3.Visible = true;
      Button1.Visible = true;
      MessagePanel.Visible = true;
}
```

and the `getuserlist` function which is:

```
protected List<string> getUserList(ListBox lb)
{
     List<string> li = new List<string>(); 
     // List<string> lista = (List<string>)Session["list"];
     foreach (ListItem l in lb.Items)
     {
          if (l.Selected)
          {
               li.Add(l.Text);
          }
     }
     Session["list"] = li;
     List<string> lista = (List<string>)Session["list"];
     return lista;               
}
```

I am not quite sure if what I want can be achieved, but if someone could help me in this it would be great!

Comment: is answer worked for you ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change this line

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

rather than creating new table you should get exisiting table

```
 DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

means get datasource of gridview which you already assigned and add row in that rather than creating new table each time

Comment: I am trying it, but instead I am changing the code, because if the  Gridview is empty, i need to declare a new datatable, else i woill bind it to the gridview's source

Comment: Ok the answer is working, with some little modifications..thank you :)